# What does _doc mean in elasticsearch sort search return?

Tags: elasticsearch

When I search with sort in elasitcsearch using _search function, I got _doc in sort field. What is the difference between it and _doc field as document type?

Elasticseach version: 6.2.2

```
"sort": [
    1577413214250, # timestamp
    393 # _doc
  ]
```

Actually, kibana also uses _doc when implement "Surrounding Documents":

```
{"index":["prophet-job-*"],"ignore_unavailable":true,"preference":1577428415532}
{"version":true,"size":5,"search_after":[1577413214250,385],"sort":[{"@timestamp":{"order":"asc","unmapped_type":"boolean"}},{"_doc":{"order":"desc","unmapped_type":"boolean"}}],"_source":{"excludes":[]},"stored_fields":["*"],"script_fields":{},"docvalue_fields":["@timestamp"],"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"match_all":{}}],"filter":[],"should":[],"must_not":[]}}}
{"index":["prophet-job-*"],"ignore_unavailable":true,"preference":1577428415532}
{"version":true,"size":5,"search_after":[1577413214250,385],"sort":[{"@timestamp":{"order":"desc","unmapped_type":"boolean"}},{"_doc":{"order":"asc","unmapped_type":"boolean"}}],"_source":{"excludes":[]},"stored_fields":["*"],"script_fields":{},"docvalue_fields":["@timestamp"],"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"match_all":{}}],"filter":[],"should":[],"must_not":[]}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

**_doc** in the context of sorting can be used if you do not care about the order, and simply want the documents to be returned in the most efficient way possible.  Think of it as a search option, as opposed to the index doc type "_doc"

For more information about sorting by **_doc**, see the official [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-body.html#request-body-search-sort).

Hi, Dennis, below is a simple sample: http://test.kibana.some.net/elasticsearch/_msearch
request paylaod:

```
{"index":["some-index-*"],"ignore_unavailable":true,"preference":1577931761749}
{"version":true,"size":5,"search_after":[1577931865123,12],"sort":[{"@timestamp":{"order":"asc","unmapped_type":"boolean"}},{"_doc":{"order":"desc","unmapped_type":"boolean"}}],"_source":{"excludes":[]},"stored_fields":["*"],"script_fields":{},"docvalue_fields":["@timestamp"],"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"match_all":{}}],"filter":[],"should":[],"must_not":[]}}}
{"index":["some-index-*"],"ignore_unavailable":true,"preference":1577931761749}
{"version":true,"size":5,"search_after":[1577931865123,12],"sort":[{"@timestamp":{"order":"desc","unmapped_type":"boolean"}},{"_doc":{"order":"asc","unmapped_type":"boolean"}}],"_source":{"excludes":[]},"stored_fields":["*"],"script_fields":{},"docvalue_fields":["@timestamp"],"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"match_all":{}}],"filter":[],"should":[],"must_not":[]}}}
```

and the partial response is

```
{
  "_index": "some-index-2020.01.02",
  "_type": "doc",
  "_id": "123456",
  "_version": 1,
  "_score": null,
  "_source": {
    "@timestamp": "2020-01-02T02:24:25.123Z",
    "prospector": {
      "type": "log"
    },
    "@version": "1",
    "tags": [
      "beats_input_codec_plain_applied"
    ],
    "fields": {
      "some-values": "xxxxxx"
    },
    "message": "[2020-01-02 10:24:24] [INFO] [evaluation.py:277] Finished evaluation at 2020-01-02-02:24:24"
  },
  "fields": {
    "@timestamp": [
      "2020-01-02T02:24:25.123Z"
    ]
  },
  "sort": [
    1577931865123,
    11 # this is _doc value
  ]
}
```

The second time I search the same thing, response has the same content except _doc value changed to 12, so I'm confused about the definition of this field.

Comment: Hi, Dennis, thanks for your answer, that makes some sense, but I'm still confused about the value of this fields, since it seems to be changed for multiple times of search for the same content.

Comment: Can you please post a sample search and response?  I'm not quiet sure I understand

Comment: Hi, Dennis, sorry I've unintentionally changed your answer by mistake. But the added contents is an extra clarification about my question. Hope that helps you understand it.